# Twilight intensity levels

Tags: visible-light

I'm wondering if anyone has made a graph of light intensity during twilight on a clear morning/evening? I'd be interested in information such as light intensity in Lux, when the twilight becomes more intense than moonlight, etc.

Comment: Celestia package has appendix with technical explanation and references. Perhaps you could look there.  Lux will depend how do you orient your eye / camera/ detector or whatever surface with respect to sky.